# Conversion between short* to int*

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

Assuming `short` is 2 bytes and `int` is 4 bytes on a 32 bit OS. Is the following an undefined behavior?

```
short s = 42;
int *p = (int*)(&s);
```

Comment: Back in the day when we were porting our software from Vax Ultrix to Sun OS 3, these sorts of things bit us on the ass a lot.  Mostly because of casts from int to short, which on big-endian Vax was fine but on little-endian MC68030 made for a lot of variables suddenly becoming `0`.

Comment: Why do you think it could be an undefined behavior?

Comment: What would that even do if it were allowed? You've got two bytes, and you're trying to read/write four (depending on what you'll be doing with p). That's a bad idea no matter the language rules.

Comment: Memory alignment is the first thing that screams at me when doing this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the code that you have posted does not exhibit *undefined behavior* but attempting to read `*p` would. Also, depending on the alignment requirements of `int` and `short`, the result of the cast may be unspecified and irreversable (see 5.2.10 [expr.reinterpret.cast] / 7).

See ISO/IEC 14882:2011 3.10 [basic.lval] / 10:

> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined:
>
> - the dynamic type of the object,
> - a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type similar (as defined in 4.4) to the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its elements or non-static data members (including, recursively, an element or non-static data member of a subaggregate or contained union),
> - a type that is a (possibly cv-qualified) base class type of the dynamic type of the object,
> - a char or unsigned char type.

The object that you are trying to access is a `short` and `*p` is a *glvalue* of type `int` which doesn't meet any of the above descriptions.

Comment: If I go from `int*` to `short*`, would it still be undefined to access value pointed by `int*` using `short*`? I can only use a `char*` right?

Comment: @user1086635: Yes, you are correct. The logic and reasoning are exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is directly in the realm of UB, as you are reading two uninitialized bytes.
However, the opposite,

```
int b
short* f = (short *) &b
```

will probably work due to the semantics of the little endian architecture.

(This is all assuming the compiler doesn't do anything stupid)

From wikipedia:

> The little-endian system has the property that the same value can be
>   read from memory at different lengths without using different
>   addresses (even when alignment restrictions are imposed). For example,
>   a 32-bit memory location with content 4A 00 00 00 can be read at the
>   same address as either 8-bit (value = 4A), 16-bit (004A), 24-bit
>   (00004A), or 32-bit (0000004A), all of which retain the same numeric
>   value. Although this little-endian property is rarely used directly by
>   high-level programmers, it is often employed by code optimizers as
>   well as by assembly language programmers.

So, as long as you are little endian, the opposite direction should be fine.

Still undefined behavior though.

Comment: This is wrong. Firstly, what you say applies to reading an int using a short*, not the other way around: reading two bytes of uninitialised memory will change the results. Secondly, compilers can and do optimise based on the assumption that you won't access objects using the wrong type, even if the hardware allows it.

Comment: "as you are reading two uninitialized bytes" I'm sorry, but I do not see the "read" in `int *p = (int*)(&s);`